# ContentControl inside TabItem doesn't resize proberly

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, resize, contentcontrol

I have a `ContentControl` inside a `TabItem`. The `ContentControl` displays a `UserControl`. My Problem is the `Width` of the `ContentControl` isn't set corectly, it is way to big. The `Height` is correctly displayd.
I want to `SizeToContent` because I have multiple `TabItems` with different sizes.
I have the following code:

**MainWindow.xaml** (Short Version)

```
<Window Height="350" Width="525" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<DockPanel>
    <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Left" TabStripPlacement="Left">
        <TabItem Header="BDE Config" IsEnabled="{Binding LoggedIn}">
            <Grid>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

The `UserControl` doesn't has `Width`/`Height` `Properties`. So why is it that the `Height` is correct but the `Width` way to big for my Screen.

**XAML of the UserControl:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="BDE_Config2015.Views.BDEConfig"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BDE_Config2015"
         xmlns:h="clr-namespace:BDE_Config2015.Helpers"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Background="{StaticResource AppBg}" d:DesignHeight="655" d:DesignWidth="1180">    
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--1-->
    <GroupBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Header="BDE-Benutzer">
        <ComboBox Height="23" DisplayMemberPath="Benutzername" SelectedValuePath="Kbez" ItemsSource="{Binding BDEConfigModel.BDEBenutzer}" SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentUser}" />
    </GroupBox>
    <!--2-->
    <TabControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,3,0,0">
        <TabItem Header="BDE">
            <Grid x:Name="gBDEKonfig">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--Row 0-->
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="Buttons pro Reiter" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Name="txtBDEReiter" Margin="0,0,0,5" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="Hintergrundfarbe" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,5" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <Button Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0,0,5" Visibility="Collapsed">...</Button>
                <!--Row 1-->
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="BDE-Titel" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,5" Text="{Binding BDETitel, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" />
                <!--Row 2-->
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="BDE-Belegung"/>
                <!--Row 3-->
                <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding BDEConfigModel.Clientoptionen}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding crBDEBelegung}" Name="dgvBDEBelegung" CellEditEnding="DGV_CellEditEnding" CurrentCellChanged="DGV_CurrentCellChanged"
                              h:DataGridBehavior.AutoScrollIntoView="True" SelectionMode="Single">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Nummer, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="Nr" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OptionText, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="Arbeitsplatztitel" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OptionInfo, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="Buttonbezeichnung"/>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Anlage" Width="*">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Anlage" SelectedValuePath="FertigungsStättenID" SelectedValue="{Binding OptionZahl}" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.BDEConfigModel.Fertigungsstaette, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.siFertigungsstaette, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
                                    </ComboBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Arbeitsplatz" Width="*">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Arbeitsplatzbez" SelectedValuePath="ArbeitsPlatzNummer" SelectedValue="{Binding OptionGanzzahl}" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.BDEConfigModel.Arbeitsplatz, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.siArbeitsplatz, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
                                    </ComboBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
                <!--Row 4-->
                <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5" Command="{Binding NeuBDEBelegungCommand}">Neu</Button>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5" Command="{Binding LoeschenBDEBelegungCommand}">Löschen</Button>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Arbeitsgang/Arbeitsplan">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Arbeitsplan"/>
                <DataGrid Grid.Row="1">

                </DataGrid>
                <CheckBox Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Unabhängig vom Arbeitsplan" Margin="0,10,5,0" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="Arbeitsgang"/>
                <DataGrid Grid.Row="4">

                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="ColumnsManagement">
            <Grid Margin="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Arbeitsplatz" Margin="5,0" />
                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,5,5" ItemsSource="{Binding BDEConfigModel.BDEArbeitsplatz}" DisplayMemberPath="OptionText" SelectedValuePath="PKID" 
                              SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedArbeitsplatzCM}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="DataSource" Margin="5,0" />
                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" Margin="5,0,5,5" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDataSource}">
                        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                            <x:Array Type="sys:String" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
                                <sys:String>proc_BDEoW_ChargeStartDetail</sys:String>
                                <sys:String>proc_BDEoW_ChargeProduktion</sys:String>
                            </x:Array>
                        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                    </ComboBox>
                    <Button Grid.Column="4" Content="Laden" Width="85" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,0,5,5" Command="{Binding LadenCMCommand}"/>
                </Grid>
                <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding BDEConfigModel.ArbeitsplatzSpaltenManagement}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                          IsEnabled="{Binding EnabledCM}" SelectedValue="{Binding crArbeitsplatzSM}" h:DataGridBehavior.AutoScrollIntoView="True">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="Spalte" Binding="{Binding SQLVisibleColumns}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Titel" Binding="{Binding SQLVisibleColumnsName}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="%Weite" Binding="{Binding SQLVisibleColumnsWidth}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="ReadOnly" Binding="{Binding SQLVisibleColumnsAccess}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding MessageCM}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Neu" Margin="5" Command="{Binding NeuCMCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding EnabledCM}" />
                    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Löschen" Margin="5" Command="{Binding LoeschenCMCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding EnabledCM}" />
                    <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Con. Kopieren" Margin="5" Command="{Binding KopierenCMCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding EnabledCM}" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="3" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="5" Text="{Binding SummeCM}"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="4" Content="Speichern" Margin="5" Command="{Binding SpeichernCMCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding EnabledCM}" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <!--3-->
    <GroupBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Header="Modul-Info" Name="gbModulInfo" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding BDEConfigModel.BDEModul}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding crModulInfo}" h:DataGridBehavior.AutoScrollIntoView="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Typ}" Header="Typ" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Bezeichnung}" Header="Bezeichnung" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="V Spez." Margin="5" Command="{Binding VSpezCommand}"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="V Global" Margin="5" Command="{Binding VGlobalCommand}"/>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
    <!--4-->
    <GroupBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Header="Register" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid Name="gRegister">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding BDEConfigModel.Register}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding crRegister}" h:DataGridBehavior.AutoScrollIntoView="True" CellEditEnding="DGV_CellEditEnding" CurrentCellChanged="DGV_CurrentCellChanged">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Nummer, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="Nr" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OptionText, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="Registername" Width="*"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Neu" Margin="5" Command="{Binding NeuRegisterCommand}" />
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="Löschen" Margin="5" Command="{Binding LoeschenRegisterCommand}" />
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
    <!--5-->
    <GroupBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Header="Spez. Modulzuordnung" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <DataGrid Name="dgvMZ" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding BDEConfigModel.BDEMZ}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
                         CanUserReorderColumns="False" SelectedValue="{Binding crMZ}" h:DataGridBehavior.AutoScrollIntoView="True" CellEditEnding="DGV_CellEditEnding" CurrentCellChanged="DGV_CurrentCellChanged">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Modul}" Header="Typ" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Modullevel, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="Level" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Parameter1, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="Parameter" Width="*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ModulSetup, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="Setup" Width="*"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Löschen" Margin="5" Command="{Binding LoeschenMZCommand}"/>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
    <!--6-->
    <GroupBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Header="Global Modulzuordnung" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <DataGrid Name="dgvMZGlobal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding BDEConfigModel.BDEMZGlobal}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
                      CanUserReorderColumns="False" SelectedValue="{Binding crMZGlobal}" h:DataGridBehavior.AutoScrollIntoView="True" CellEditEnding="DGV_CellEditEnding" 
                      CurrentCellChanged="DGV_CurrentCellChanged">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Modul}" Header="Typ" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Modullevel, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="Level"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Parameter1, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="Parameter" Width="*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ModulSetup, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="Setup" Width="*"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Löschen" Margin="5" Command="{Binding LoeschenMZGlobalCommand}"/>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It will be something in the XAML for your user control. Try adding that XAML to your question.

Comment: I have added the `XAML` of the `User Control`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be related to a strange interaction between the `SizeToContent` property on the window and the "star-sizing" on the data grid columns.

Either set the window's `SizeToContent` property to `Height` and explicitly set a width for the window, or limit the width of the star-sized columns by setting their `MaxWidth` properties to some suitable limit.

[This thread on CodePlex](https://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/38679) describes the problem. Apparently things used to be worse in that an exception would be thrown! From a post at the very bottom of that thread:

> The exception has been fixed but it's still not working properly. When placed in a user control with *(sic)* doesn't have a fixed width, setting "*" on column width will cause the column to be extremely wide (several thousand pixel), and this happens both at design time and run time.

---

As an aside, you could get rid of *a lot* of XAML markup by using `StackPanel` and `DockPanel` containers rather than using a `Grid` for everything.

Comment: It works. But now if the all `Columns` have their `maxWidth` this empty `Column` appears at the last `Column`. Any Idea how to avoid that?

Comment: If you want to have the columns star-sized then you'll have to remove their `MaxWidth` property and constrain the width of the data grid further up the visual tree, whether that's at the tab item, user control or window level. I'm pretty certain that you can't have it both ways (ie. star-sized columns *and* an automatically sized window).

Answer (score 0):

After some more trying I have found an Answert that works for me. I have done the following:

```
MaxWidth="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Left="{Binding winLeft, Mode=TwoWay}" Top="{Binding winTop, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

It sets the `MaxWidth` of the `Window` the the `Screen Width` and then whenever a `User Control` with `Star-Sized Columns` is loaded it also sets the `Position` to 0,0.